# Firebase ref() error when using variable value as parameter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing an issue while trying to access some data in Firebase. In test and develop, I'm setting the database reference in the source code and it works.

But when setting a value assigned to a variable from an input:text, it doesn't works.

This is the code:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var encuentra = $(producto).val();
var database = firebase.database();
var referencia = database.ref(encuentra);
var reportes={};
referencia.once('value', function(datos)
{
    reportes=datos.val();
    $.each(reportes, function(indice,valor){//shows the data}
```

Setting database.ref("xxx") in the source code, works fine. But when using a variable, looks like it doesn't take it in the same way; Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you `console.log(encuentra)`, what does it show?

Comment: yea console.log would help, there might be some extra space or next lines in encuentra

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your support. When console.log(encuentra) it shows the value in the same way it does when using alarm(encuentra); also, I want to add that the var encuentra gets data in date format (yyyy/mm/dd) from an input:text that uses a datepicker.